# Need help to parse name from static json

Tags: javascript, json

How would I parse this json using jquery? I'm new to json so unable to do this. I need to parse name (imran) and follower name (ali & noor) from below json.

> {"data":[{"data":{"name":"Imran","email":"imran@example.com","phone":"+9221-000000","location":"khi,pk","userid":"1114","date":"July 7, 2012, 5:39 am","privacy":"0","type":"0","last_updated":"September 11, 2012, 8:59 am","images_count":0,"component":"profile"},"0":null,"1":null,"2":[{"following":{"frienduserid":"1353","name":"Haider"}},{"following":{"frienduserid":"1148","name":"Ali"}}],"3":[{"follower":{"userid":"1148","name":"Ali"}},{"follower":{"userid":"1054","name":"noor"}}]}]}

Comment: Unless this is something return from a call to $.ajax not much jQuery will do for you

Comment: Actually i don't know how to use post method with jquery.ajax i write following code to get this json,

function myjson(){    
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("POST", "index.php",true);
var params = "userid=1114&token=XXX&action=profile";

httpObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpObject.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
httpObject.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
httpObject.send(params); 
httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

A very simple PHP example:

```
<php?

// Convert JSON to an associative array
$arr = json_decode('{"data":[{"data":{"name":"Imran","email":"imran@example.com","phone":"+9221-000000","location":"khi,pk","userid":"1114","date":"July 7, 2012, 5:39 am","privacy":"0","type":"0","last_updated":"September 11, 2012, 8:59 am","images_count":0,"component":"profile"},"0":null,"1":null,"2":[{"following":{"frienduserid":"1353","name":"Haider"}},{"following":{"frienduserid":"1148","name":"Ali"}}],"3":[{"follower":{"userid":"1148","name":"Ali"}},{"follower":{"userid":"1054","name":"noor"}}]}]}', true);

// Dump the element containing the name
var_dump($arr['data'][0]['data']['name']);

// Loop through followers and dump each follower's name
foreach ($arr['data'][0][3] as $item)
{
    var_dump($item['follower']['name']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually i'm sorry i was forget to mention that i need this to be with jquery, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure seems pretty messy... maybe you should review it. However I think you should be able to access desired data through:

```
jsonObject = JSON.Parse(yourJSONString) //This will create your jsonObject
jsonObject.data[0].data.name --> should hold the name
jsonObject.data[0].data["2"][2].follower.name --> should hold de name of the first follower.
```

Comment: yeah its quite messy json that's why hard for me to parse, i tried your code but still unable to get the result